# Copy failed error in docker no such file or directory

Tags: c#, docker

I am getting this error while creating docker image .so i do not know i resolve this .

I am building basic .netcore application in VS2019

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VxUM.png)
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ebq.png)
what changes i have to do to remove this error

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
```

to

```
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
```

and

```
COPY . .
```

to

```
COPY . WebApplication5


> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj"
COPY . WebApplication5
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication5"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication5.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication5.dll"]
```

Comment: this not working i am getting same error in above command after changing

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally i found a sol for this question.

this actually VS follow new pattern to execute a docker outside the VS.

their is no change require inside any command of docker file.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile ..
```

it generate a image with none as tag . you can rename using id

```
docker tag Id imagename
```

for more information you can follow this[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#building-from-the-command-line) link

Answer (score 0):

I think the path or the name you define is wrong:

```
COPY ["WebApplication5/WebApplication5.csproj", "WebApplication5/"]
```

change your path to:

```
COPY *.csproj ./src
```

Comment: Step 7/17 : COPY COPY *.csproj ./src
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder230862661/COPY: no such file or directory  I am getting same error

Comment: why u have two 'COPY ' here is a typo?

Comment: i created this program in VS 2019 where this docker file come by default

Comment: sorry for two copy .

Comment: Step 7/17 : COPY *.csproj ./src
 ---> 05656c24b195
Step 8/17 : RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"
 ---> Running in d57a44487798
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: Add this property to your .csproj
<Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run production" />
</Target>